# How to centralize snapshots folder in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, snapshot

I am in a project where I have to build a React UI. As it is a small project & I'm alone on it, I'd try to develop it with TypeScript & a TDD approach.

I learnt practises, installed Jest & Enzyme.
What I understood is there is a __snapshot__ directory wherever there is a snpashot test. Is there a way to centralize all the snapshots in a specific path?

The idea behind the question is to keep the project folder as clean & readable as possible, without adding a __snapshot__ folder in each component folder.

One way to get a convenient behaviour is to store all tests in a src/tests folder, to get a src/tests/__snapshots__ folder, but I'd rather to keep components tests in components folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create [custom snapshot resolver](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#snapshotresolver-string) in your jest.config file. Link has an example of code which does what you want.

```
module.exports = {

  // resolves from test to snapshot path
  resolveSnapshotPath: (testPath, snapshotExtension) =>
  testPath.replace('__tests__', '__snapshots__') + snapshotExtension,

  // resolves from snapshot to test path
  resolveTestPath: (snapshotFilePath, snapshotExtension) =>  
    snapshotFilePath
    .replace('__snapshots__', '__tests__')
    .slice(0, -snapshotExtension.length),

  // Example test path, used for preflight consistency check of the implementation above
  testPathForConsistencyCheck: 'some/__tests__/example.test.js',
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you!<br/>
<br/>
I'm trying to make it work, I had to pass the config extension from *.json* to *.js* to allow function properties, but I get console warnings:  
<br/>
```bash
● Validation Warning:
Unknown option "resolveSnapshotPath" with value (testPath, snapshotExtension) =>
    testPath.replace('__tests__', '__snapshots__') + snapshotExtension was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

```<br/>
Same for the 2 others

Comment: Do you have the latest version of jest?

Comment: Hi @DimaVishnyakov,  
  
Yes, I checked it & had the latest version of jest. But it is clear now, I just misunderstood what I had to do: I tried to put "resolveSnapshotPath" & the other properties directly in jest config file, instead of put these in another module called by the "snapshotResolver" config file property. My English level in involved in this issue ::
Thank you for the help btw !

Comment: Already did it, but always too new on StackOverflow to get my votes taken on board :]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

I tried to put **resolveSnapshotPath** and the 2 other properties directly in the jest config file.
I misunderstood what I had to do: Put these files in a new module & call this file by binding the path to it to the **snapshotResolver** jest config file property.

I always don't really know what are the purposes of each resolver property but as it works, I should get it with some tests.